# How to get a stairway symbol in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am looking for a 'stair' or 'stairway' symbol that I can use in math mode to denote a stair-like curve, for example to be used as an integration path. I have included some pictures as examples below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

and for "full" stairs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Feel free to add more appropriate tags.

Comment: There might be something [here](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @luchonacho: I thought so too, but I wasn't able to find anything even remotely close in there. Maybe I have overlooked something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could build something on your own, like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol,tikz,xcolor, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{stairwayStyleLineWidth/.style={line width=0.04em}}
\tikzset{stairwayStyleRound/.style={line join=round,line cap=round,stairwayStyleLineWidth}}
\tikzset{stairwayStyleSharp/.style={stairwayStyleLineWidth}}
\tikzset{stairwayStyle/.style={stairwayStyleRound}}

\newcommand{\stairwayup}{\mathbin{
\tikz[baseline=(stairwayanchor.base)]{
    \node (stairwayanchor) {\quad}; 
    \draw[stairwayStyle] 
        ($(stairwayanchor.south west) + (0.0em,0.4em)$)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) %-- ++(0,0.25em)
        ;
}}
}

\newcommand{\stairwaydown}{\mathbin{
\tikz[baseline=(stairwayanchor.base)]{
    \node (stairwayanchor) {\quad}; 
    \draw[stairwayStyle] 
        ($(stairwayanchor.south east) + (0.0em,0.4em)$)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) %-- ++(0,-0.25em)
        ;
}}
}

\newcommand{\stairwayupfilled}{\mathbin{
\tikz[baseline=(stairwayanchor.base)]{
    \node (stairwayanchor) {\quad}; 
    \draw[stairwayStyle,fill=.] 
        ($(stairwayanchor.south west) + (0.0em,0.4em)$)
        -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) %-- ++(0,0.25em)
        -- ++(0,-0.60em)
        -- cycle
        ;
}}
}

\newcommand{\stairwayuphollow}{\mathbin{
\tikz[baseline=(stairwayanchor.base)]{
    \node (stairwayanchor) {\quad}; 
    \draw[stairwayStyle] 
        ($(stairwayanchor.south west) + (0.0em,0.4em)$)
        -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(0.20em,0) %-- ++(0,0.25em)
        -- ++(0,-0.60em)
        -- cycle
        ;
}}
}

\newcommand{\stairwaydownfilled}{\mathbin{
\tikz[baseline=(stairwayanchor.base)]{
    \node (stairwayanchor) {\quad}; 
    \draw[stairwayStyle,fill=.] 
        ($(stairwayanchor.south east) + (0.0em,0.4em)$)
        -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) %-- ++(0,-0.25em)
        -- ++(0,-0.60em)
        -- cycle
        ;
}}
}

\newcommand{\stairwaydownhollow}{\mathbin{
\tikz[baseline=(stairwayanchor.base)]{
    \node (stairwayanchor) {\quad}; 
    \draw[stairwayStyle] 
        ($(stairwayanchor.south east) + (-0.0em,0.4em)$)
        -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) -- ++(0,0.20em)
        -- ++(-0.20em,0) %-- ++(0,-0.25em)
        -- ++(0,-0.60em)
        -- cycle
        ;
}}
}



\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

The symbols used in Text $\stairwayupfilled \stairwayup \stairwayuphollow$ and $\stairwaydownfilled \stairwaydown \stairwaydownhollow$ and formulas:
\begin{align*}
    &5\stairwayup6 \stairwaydown 7 \\
    &\int_{\stairwayup} \omega, \int_{\stairwaydown} \omega\\
    &\stairwayupfilled \stairwayup \stairwayuphollow \\
    &\stairwaydownfilled \stairwaydown \stairwaydownhollow 
\end{align*}

Different sizes and widths: 

{\tiny $\stairwayup <$} 

{\huge $\stairwayup <$}

\begin{align*}
        {\tiny\stairwayup}
        {\huge\stairwayup}
\end{align*}

Color:
\begin{align*}
    \colorbox{blue}{\color{-blue} $\stairwayupfilled \stairwayup \stairwayuphollow$}
\end{align*}

Normalsize:
\begin{align*}
    6   &\stairwayup 5 \stairwaydown 7\\
    6   &> 5<7\\
    \int_{\stairwayup}  & \int_{\stairwaydown}
\end{align*}

\tiny Tiny:
\begin{align*}
    6   &\stairwayup 5 \stairwaydown 7\\
    6   &> 5<7\\
    \int_{\stairwayup}  & \int_{\stairwaydown}
\end{align*}

\huge Huge:
\begin{align*}
    6   &\stairwayup 5 \stairwaydown 7\\
    6   &> 5<7\\
    \int_{\stairwayup}  & \int_{\stairwaydown}
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Observe that the stairs have a round appeal. This way they blend better with `<`. You can choose sharp corners if you change

```
\tikzset{stairwayStyle/.style={stairwayStyleRound}}
```

to

```
\tikzset{stairwayStyle/.style={stairwayStyleSharp}}
```

if you want to. The thickness of the strokes varies with the font size and the symbols do change their color appropriately.

Ti*k*z is very versatile once you have a basic understanding. It might be relatively slow compared to other low level software, though. My code might have some room for improvement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this and for the code example! I am still very new to tikz, so the code example really helps!

Comment: @M.G. Ti*k*Z is definitely worth learning. It comes with a great manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf.

Comment: Thanks for including the other examples as well!

Comment: @M.G. You may find http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ useful, too.

Answer (score 19):

Yet another question of this type: I begin to think that I should seriously consider the idea of turning my [`halloweenmath` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath) into a package generally aimed to making mathematical symbols out of arbitrary pictures.  In this way, you get several frills for free, like the bolder look when the `bold` math version is in force, and automatic scaling in sub/superscripts.  I see no reason, however, why the symbols in question should behave as binary operators.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{halloweenmath} % also loads "amsmath''

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@HwM@ironwire@stairway[2]{%
  % #1 := font selector (e.g., "\textfont")
  % #2 := line thickness, in unit of default-rule-thickness "\fontdimen"
  \begin{@HwM@small@picture}#1{4.6}{-2.3}%
    \roundcap
    \linethickness{#2\@HwM@thickness@units@for #1}%
    \polyline(\-2,-2)(\-2,-1)(\-1,-1)(\-1,0)%
            (0,0)(0,1)(\+1,1)(\+1,2)(\+2,2)\relax
  \end{@HwM@small@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@HwM@Ironwire@Stairway[2]{%
  % #1 := style selector (e.g., "\textstyle")
  % #2 := font selector (e.g., "\textfont")
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses{\@HwM@ironwire@stairway #2}%
        {{1.25}}%
        {{2.5}}%
}

\newcommand*\@HwM@hollow@stairway[2]{%
  % #1 := font selector (e.g., "\textfont")
  % #2 := line thickness, in unit of default-rule-thickness "\fontdimen"
  \begin{@HwM@small@picture}#1{4.6}{-2.3}%
    \roundcap
    \linethickness{#2\@HwM@thickness@units@for #1}%
    \polygon(\-2,-2)(\-2,-1)(\-1,-1)(\-1,0)%
            (0,0)(0,1)(\+1,1)(\+1,2)(\+2,2)%
            (\+2,-2)\relax
  \end{@HwM@small@picture}%
}
\newcommand*\@HwM@Hollow@Stairway[2]{%
  % #1 := style selector (e.g., "\textstyle")
  % #2 := font selector (e.g., "\textfont")
  \@HwM@choose@thicknesses{\@HwM@hollow@stairway #2}%
        {{1.25}}%
        {{2.5}}%
}

\newcommand*\mathsimplerightstair{\@HwM@set@right@dir \@HwM@mathsimplestair}
\newcommand*\mathsimpleleftstair {\@HwM@set@left@dir  \@HwM@mathsimplestair}
\newcommand*\@HwM@mathsimplestair{%
  \@HwM@general@ordinary@symbol \@HwM@Ironwire@Stairway
}
\newcommand*\mathhollowrightstair{\@HwM@set@right@dir \@HwM@mathhollowstair}
\newcommand*\mathhollowleftstair {\@HwM@set@left@dir  \@HwM@mathhollowstair}
\newcommand*\@HwM@mathhollowstair{%
  \@HwM@general@ordinary@symbol \@HwM@Hollow@Stairway
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In text, surrounded by square brackets so to check the sidebearings:
\( [ \mathsimplerightstair \mathsimpleleftstair] \),
or \( [\mathhollowrightstair \mathhollowleftstair] \).
Now in display:
\[
    \mathsimplerightstair + \int_{\mathsimplerightstair} f(z)\,dz
        - \mathhollowleftstair - \int_{\mathhollowleftstair} g(z)\,dz
\]
Note that the symbols get smaller in the subscript, even if the main font size
doesn't change.  This behavior extends to double scripts, \emph{e.g.},
\( [\mathhollowrightstair_{\mathhollowrightstair^{\mathhollowrightstair}}] \),
as one would expect.\footnote{Of course, changes in the main font size are 
honored too:
\( [\mathhollowrightstair_{\mathhollowrightstair^{\mathhollowrightstair}}] \).}

Furthemore, compare the looks of the four symbols in the \texttt{normal} and in 
the \texttt{bold} math versions:
\( [\mathsimplerightstair \mathsimpleleftstair
\mathhollowrightstair \mathhollowleftstair] \)
{\bfseries \boldmath versus
\( [\mathsimplerightstair \mathsimpleleftstair
\mathhollowrightstair \mathhollowleftstair] \).}

As already mentioned in a footnote, the symbols also scale with the main font 
size (compare them with the brackets).

\bigskip

{\Large This is \verb|\Large|:
\( [ \mathsimplerightstair \mathsimpleleftstair] +
\mathhollowrightstair_{\mathhollowrightstair}\).}

\bigskip

{\Huge This is \verb|\Huge|:
\( [ \mathsimplerightstair \mathsimpleleftstair] +
\mathhollowrightstair_{\mathhollowrightstair}\).}

\bigskip

{\footnotesize This is \verb|\footnotesize|:
\( [ \mathsimplerightstair \mathsimpleleftstair] +
\mathhollowrightstair_{\mathhollowrightstair}\).}

\end{document}
```

See the comments in `halloweenmath.dtx` for an explanation of how the macros work.  Some fine-tuning of the sidebearings and of the line thicknesses might still be necessary, of course.

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

---

**Addition:**
It crossed my mind that, in the above code, you might want to replace all occurrences of `\roundcap` with `\roundcap \roundjoin`, to get round joins between the segments of the stairs as well as round caps; and as a matter of fact, `\roundcap` is even useless in the case of `\@HwM@hollow@stairway`, which has no caps at all!

Comment: This is great! I will admit to my shame that I wasn't aware of the existence of your package. But now I am!